# How to create a template of class with methods when creating a new java class in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a requirement where I should generate a class with same methods.

Example: in Eclipse if I create a java class it should come with predefined methods.

```
public void myClass()
{

   MYfunction.Add();

   MYfunction.Subtract();

   MYfunction.Multiple()

   MYfunction.Divide()

}
```

Next time I do in Eclipse:

`New > Java Class`

My new class should come with `public void myClass()`'s methods.

Comment: That sounds like an [X-Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) - you probably want to define an interface with these methods, create new classes that implement the interface as required and ask eclipse to auto-generate the methods that need to be implemented.

Comment: Note that the "New Java Class" dialog in Eclipse allows you to specify interfaces and base class. You'd get method stubs for everything you need to fill in in the new file.